# Problem with Grid Statistics For Polygons

Tags: qgis, saga

So honestly I have no idea what I'm doing, I'm a total beginner with GIS and I'm just following directions for an assignment given by my teacher.

I am trying to use Grid Statistics For Polygons -tool to do create statistics(?) of a raster layer

Maybe this image will give a better idea of what I'm doing: [image: example]

And the log:

```py
processing.runalg(
    "saga:gridstatisticsforpolygons", 
    "C:/Users/Name/Pictures/オマタ/H‌​17/Viheralueet.tif", 
    "C:/Users/Name/Pictures/オマタ/H17/Bufferi50.shp",
    False, False, False, False, True, False, False, False, 0,
    "C:/Users/Name/Pictures/Viherbufferi.shp")
```

I can't open the file the tool creates once I've clicked 'Run'. I'm not sure, but is the tool supposed to create a .shp -formatted file? Because the only file the tool creates is Viherbufferi.prj and I'm not able to do anything with it. According to the directions I'm supposed to be able to open the file as a new layer.

I hope someone understood my explanation!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. It's never good to have no idea. Pls try to read a little more about the basic GIS concepts (eg. [QGIS manual](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html)). The `*.prj` file is just the projection file of a Shape (*.shp), if there is non something different went wrong.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to read the manual. And yes, there's no .shp-file. Do you have any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Nope, to be honest I don't even find the [Grid statistics for polygons](http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/saga/shapes_grid/gridstatisticsforpolygons.html) tool in GIS 2.8.

Comment: Do you have any log output?

Comment: Here: processing.runalg("saga:gridstatisticsforpolygons","C:/Users/Name/Pictures/オマタ/H17/Viheralueet.tif","C:/Users/Name/Pictures/オマタ/H17/Bufferi50.shp",False,False,False,False,True,False,False,False,0,"C:/Users/Name/Pictures/Viherbufferi.shp")

Comment: It's a SAGA tool and works for me. Could be issues with the special characters in your user folder. Try to move all files to C:/temp or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Learning from discussion between OP and @underdark.

We'd better double-check a list to make sure QGIS-SAGA can understand the filepath to target dataset.

- The filepath does not include special (non-ascii) characters.
- The filepath does not include spaces.